# How to get 16-bit grayscale color picker in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

I am creating a 16-bit grayscale drawing in Photoshop. Unfortunately, the color picker doesn't show 16-bit grayscale numbers (0-32768). Without being able to input exact values, it's very difficult to choose accurate colors.

Does anyone know how to set Photoshop to show an accurate slider or how to accurately choose colors in this circumstance?

Comment: More of a side note, but AFAIK, 32-bit mode has a 32-bit picker. There is some {magic complication with gamma} that is the reason for not implementing a 16bit picker, but it is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Switch document into 16bit mode and under info box click the eyedropper icon.
(markers are made with eyedropper tool)

[image: photoshop info 16bit]

Comment: That lets you see the colors chosen, but doesn't let you choose them. Helpful tidbit, though.